# Unsure of how to access Paper props of AppBar

Tags: material-ui

Ive noted on the beta version of Material UI (https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/api/app-bar/) you can access the Paper properties via App Bar component. Its not obvious to me how this is done and so far my attempts have come up short.

Could someone share a working example or just a code snippet? That would be super helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [source](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L79) the *AppBar* component is just [a glorified *Paper*](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L93).

If you look at how `props` [are treated](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/e5a81a89efcb5054e5b9eda9f06381b3526614d0/src/AppBar/AppBar.js#L80) you’ll notice the `...other` part. That extracts all properties that are not explicitly [destructured](http://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-destructuring). This is a ES feature not yet in spec but pretty solid and more or less safe to use, it’s called [Object rest/spread](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/).

Those *rest object* is then used to pass additional properties to the *Paper* component with a JSX Spread operator `{ ...other }`.

So for example

```
<AppBar tabIndex={2} />
```

since `tabIndex` is not explicitly extracted during destructuring in the AppBar source it will be part of `other`, and therefore “passed down” to `<Paper ... />`.